# 大恋愛の末に結ばれるわけではないから、アバタもエクボということはありえなかった。先行するのは条件である。

Tags: translation, meaning, nuances, expressions

Could somebody please help me decipher the phrase above which I came across while reading 逃がした魚は大きかった。It’s about two people in relationship. I understand that the first sentence means something like “since they were not tied together through a big love, theirs wasn’t a blind love. But I cannot seem to really decipher the second sentence. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation of 先行するのは条件である is "What precedes is condition". This の is just もの or "thing". 条件 refers to what is required for a successful marriage (aside from love). Google with `結婚の条件` and you can find many articles about what people typically consider 条件. Especially in a context like this, I think 条件 mainly refers to more material and dry requirements such as income. Your understanding of the first sentence is fine.